# Remove the columns which have special condition in array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array which has a lot of column, here I only show an small example of it as

```
 a = np.array(
 [[1, 3 ,4, 5],
 [2, 4 ,7, 8], 
 [2, 7 ,9, 5], 
 [2, 96 ,8, 5]])
```

I want to delete the columns which the third row is 7 and last row is 96. Here for example, the second column has this condition.  The desired output is:

```
a = np.array(
[[1 ,4, 5],
[2 ,7, 8],
[2 ,9, 5], 
[2 ,8, 5] ])
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use boolean slicing:

```
a2 = a[:,(a[2]!=7)|(a[-1]!=96)]
```

Or with the reverse operation ([De Morgan's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
a2 = a[:,~((a[2]==7)&(a[-1]==96))]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 4, 5],
       [2, 7, 8],
       [2, 9, 5],
       [2, 8, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the index of the column that has `7` in the 3rd row and `96` in the fourth row, use `argmax` with some conditions (since `True` is 1 and `False` is 0, `argmax` will return the index of the **first** `True`), and use `np.delete` with `axis=1` to remove it:

```
indexes = np.where((a[2] == 7) & (a[3] == 96))[0]
a = np.delete(a, indexes, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 4, 5],
       [2, 7, 8],
       [2, 9, 5],
       [2, 8, 5]])
```